# How to create a apache nifi template,to get data from url?

Tags: templates, ftp, apache-nifi

I want to get the data from a ftp link and store it as a hive table.

Comment: pls can anyone suggest me the flow.

Comment: If you wish to get better assistance on this question you should frame it in terms of the exact source and destination - you have clarified below that you want to target Kylo and not just a Hive Table, so please be more clear

Answer (score 2):

ashok,

Using following processors to achieve your requirments.

```
GetFTP-->PutFile-->ReplaceText-->PutHiveQL.
```

**GetFTP**-->Gets a file from ftp server with help of hostname&port,username&credentials.

`PutFile`-->Store file from FTP into local drive.

`ReplaceText`-->Search flowfile content &replace it with your hive query in which having putFile location to specify downloaded file to load into hive.

`PutHiveQL`-->Executes hive query present in flowfile.

Please let me know if you have any queries

Comment: file:///home/idealabs/Pictures/LocalAndRdbms.png

Comment: i am new to apache nifi,pls can u clarify my doubt.I want to upload this template into kylo.But i have one example template i.e,to load local file or RDBMS data into kylo.In that they didn't use puthiveql. Here  i am sharing the screenshot link   file:///home/idealabs/Pictures/LocalAndRdbms.png

Comment: your question is not said data into kylo. It only said ftp data into hive only using NiFi right?

Comment: yes,but kylo backend table is hive only.After posting the question i found that example.I want to get data from ftp and store it into the kylo.

Comment: please give me a solution ,to get data from ftp to kylo